# Android App can't access Vagrant Homestead hosted Web API

Tags: php, android, vagrant, laravel-5, retrofit2

**Note:**
I'm new to Laravel, Vagrant-Homestead setup, and Android's networking library Retrofit. But I'm good in Android and PHP Web development. However I setup Laravel, developed a simple test web API, just to test Retrofit library in Android App. And also please don't mark this as a Duplicate Question of the following [Q&A thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838399/access-to-homestead-host-from-genymotion). Even though it asks the same alike question, these questions are different.

**My Problem:**
My Vagrant-Homestead hosted web API I can access through the web browser installed in host OS X Mac. And also my Homestead has two Laravel sites ll5.app and tapi.app (which is the API).

```
 _____________Mac OS X on MB Pro___________________
|  _______________            ______________      |
| | Vagrant       |          |              |     |
| |http://api.app | <------> | Web Browser  |     | IP: 192.168.1.7
| |_______________|          |______________|     |
|_________________________________________________|

But, I still couldn't fix this up for the following:

 _____________Mac OS X on MB Pro_______________________
|  __________________            ________________      |
| | Vagrant          |          |                |     |
| |http://api.app    | <---X--> | Android App    |     |
| | IP:192.168.10.10 |          |IP:192.168.56.1 |     |
| |__________________|          |________________|     |
|______________________________________________________|
```

My Host file looks like follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   ll5.app
192.168.10.10   tapi.app
```

And following is just a part of my `Homestead.yaml`:

```
folders:
    - map: "/Users/randika/Private_Projects/webapps/"
      to: "/home/vagrant/webapps"

sites:
    - map: tapi.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/webapps/test_api/public"
    - map: ll5.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/webapps/ll5/public"
```

I tried giving following things to try out a web service call using Retrofit library.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("<address>")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

For the <address> I tried giving following values:
        http://tapi.app
        192.168.10.10:8000
```

When I try to access the this using Genymotion Android's Web Browser and the address as http://192.168.10.10:8000, it loads the ll5.app home page not the API.

How to resolve this problem? Any help is appreciated.
At least just tell me that this can't be done?

**P.S.:** It's already 1+ AM in the morning and I've been struggling with this from the last weekend!

Comment: This IP address seems to be unreachable by your Android App. Could you explain why the IP address of your Android App is different?

Comment: Actually it's not IP Address of the Android App, it's (IP:192.168.56.1) the IP of the Genymotion as I found out.

Comment: Show your vagrant config. Essentially `config.vm.network` value

Comment: @AlexBlex where could I find this? is it in the `Vagrantfile`? If so I checked inside it but there's no such value set up!

Comment: Ok. I think it's a communication problem. Your android app can't reach your vagrant box. Try to create a network between your boxes. Assuming you're using virtualbox, take a look, maybe it helps: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had not to give up this problem and resolve it once and for all. Because I'm fed up with going to find web hosts whenever I need to host something and publicly share it among my colleagues.

**Answer Skeleton:** This includes you following things:

**Must To-Do things:**

- Modifying your hosts file
- Modifying Nginx files inside vagrant

**Optional To-Do things:**

- Create an Atlas Account and use `vagrant share` feature to share to access to access your Vagrant-Homestead Laravel development app anywhere in the world over the Internet.

**Answer Step by Step:**

**1.** **Intro about my Mac + Vagrant + Homestead environment.**

**My Host MacBook current IP Address:** 192.168.1.7

**My Vagrant-Homestead IP Defined within the Homestead.yaml:** 192.168.10.10

I have told before within my Question, I have multiple sites (ll5.app and tapi.app). So following is part of my **Homestead.yaml** which has mapped those **multiple sites**.

```
folders:
     - map: "/Users/randika/Private_Projects/webapps/"
       to: "/home/vagrant/webapps"

 sites:
     - map: tapi.app
       to: "/home/vagrant/webapps/test_api/public"
     - map: ll5.app
       to: "/home/vagrant/webapps/ll5/public"
```

Ok, now we are good to go to the second step. Sorry above portion of Hosts file is not code-formatted due to an editor bug.

**2.** I modified my `hosts` file as follows:

> Note that I've mapped my current IP address with the Vagrant IP address.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   tapi.app
192.168.10.10   ll5.app
192.168.1.7     192.168.10.10
```

And save it.

**3.** Start your vagrant and provision.

```
 cd Homestead/
 vagrant up
 vagrant provision
```

**4.** And let's go to edit our Nginx files inside the vagrant. Login to vagrant via ssh.

```
 vagrant ssh
```

You should see a vagrant ssh prompt like follows: **vagrant@homestead:~$**

**5.** Now let's go eddit our Nginx configuration files for each of our provisioned Vagrant hosted web apps.

```
 cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
 ls
```

You would see the list of web app config as follows(according to my setup):

```
 ll5.app  tapi.app
```

Out of those two web apps I wanted to access `tapi.app` via the Android Genymotion, but even though when I give Vagrants VirtualBox IP or Vagrant IP addresses it was not available to access because I have multiple sites hosted in vagrant homestead. If it is a single site setup then I's able to access via the Vagrant IP Address.
Get your required App related Nginx Config file as follow: (this step assumes that you know the very basics of Vim editor).

```
 sudo vim tapi.app     ----> This will give you the chances to edit that NginX config file.
```

It was like following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name tapi.app;
  root "/home/vagrant/webapps/test_api/public";
```

And change it to look like following:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 default ssl;
  server_name tapi.app;
  root "/home/vagrant/webapps/test_api/public";
```

I hope that you noticed the following two lines:

```
 listen 80;    to    listen 80 default_server;
 listen 443;   to    listen 443 default ssl;
```

Ok, and now save the **Nginx Config** file and quit from Vim editor.

**6.** Now the final essential command, to be executed within the `vagrant ssh`:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

If you have followed the above steps up to the last one, then now you might have got the answer to your question (I've got the answer for my question after trying to resolve this for the past 5 nights with lesser sleep hours :D ). 
 **Note:** After the reload of Nginx, don't go to provision the vagrant once again, because if you do so the above Nginx configuration files will be re-written over your edits.

**Precautions:**

Please keep in mind that, we edited the Nginx Config file just to make one of our site to be served by default via the server, so these steps were carried out just because we have **multiple sites** within our Vagrant-Homestead box. So after we are done with what we wanted, **we should rollback the changes we did to that particular Nginx Config file the same way we accessed it via Vagrant SSH.** Else if you keep this change as it is your other sites won't be working well as they were. [For further readings please read the following thread.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/accessing-homesteadvagrant-site-from-different-device-on-same-network)

**Optional To-Do things:**

- Let's say that you want one of your projects (web API or web app) developed under Vagrant-Homestead, and you want to share it with your colleagues over the internet? And you have another bunch of sites in it too (that's why we struggled above steps). So that's also possible which we call (`vagrant share`). So I have edited the **Nginx file** and informed the server that which site do I need to serve as the default one, so by doing Vagrant share, this will now serve that site via the Shared URL. So let's start doing it:

[Visit this link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/) just to get some background idea about what we are gonna do.

**Vagrant Share Steps:**

1. [Visit the following link](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/account/new) and create your Atlas Account.
2. Exit from Vagrant ssh just by typing exit, and inside the Homestead directory, login to vagrant like follow:

   `vagrant login`
3. Give your Atlas Account details (username and password) respectively when it prompts to you.
4. Final step of vagrant share is, vagrant share itself. Do it as follows:

   `vagrant share`

   And this should give you a result out put like the following, with globally accessible Temporary URL, which lasts until you stop sharing with the **Ctrl+C** command.

[image: Vagrant Share URL]

Hope this answer will be helpful to somebody else and will save few hours of their life time.

Cheers to All The Engineers in this Planet!

Comment: Hello dude thanks for all the effort. Right now I'm where you were, but I've done exactly as you said but still my android emulator can't connect to the website which is up and running. The thing is Xcode can use the api of my local website pretty easily but the damn android emulator can't. I'm on a mac with virtual box and laravel homestead with android emulator. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [public network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html) for your vagrant box to be accessible from other devices. E.g.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

Private network makes it accessible from host system only.
Please, be aware of security implications.

Comment: Please, guide me a little more. Where should I put the above lines?

Comment: Is it okay if I put that `config.vm.network` line as follows?
`Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.network "public_network"
    `

Comment: yep. It will use DHCP to assign public IP address to your VM box

Comment: Please read the [documentation page](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html) about other options available. It may worth to assign static IP to be sure it does not change.

Comment: Actually this didn't work for me. I added the above line just as it has suggested and did `vagrant provision` also, but it still doesn't work. So I removed non-api Laravel project from Vagrant-Homestead and tried to access the API by the IP address given to the Vagrant and it works. So there must be a special case of configuration to do to use it with multiple sites.

Comment: Alex actually for me it didn't work your simple answer. But anyway thanks for your time. And please check my answer. I've practically done that and achieved more than what I needed. Cheers!